# What im doing wrong?

Tags: node.js, json, express

I'm try to loop through json file and, what I'm doing wrong ?

```
index.js file:

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var file = require('data.json')
  var data = JSON.stringify(file)
  res.render('index', { title: 'test', objs: data });

  console.log(data)
});

index.pug file:




extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}
  ul
    each obj in objs
      li= obj
```

Its working but i have something like this:

[ 
{ 
" 
i
m
a
g
e
"
:
"
h
t
t
p
:
/
/
p
l
a
c
e
h
o
l
d
.
i
t
/
1
5
0
x
5
0

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: And what would be the expected output? You seem to be passing the `data` as `string`, thus the `each` in the template just loops over all characters in the string.

Comment: you need to pass plain json object to your view, but you made it a `string` using `JSON.stringify()` and pass that string to the view.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `index.js` file as follows:

```javascript
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var data = require('data.json')
  console.log(data)
  return res.render('index', { title: 'test', objs: data });  
});
```

Comment: [object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]

Comment: what is the content of `data.json`?

Comment: my data.json file looks like this:
[
 {
  "image":"http://placehold.it/150x50",
  "title":"Project 1",
               "content":"content project 1",
  "link":"#"
 },
 {
  "image":"http://placehold.it/100x50",
  "title":"Project 2",
                "content":"content project 2",
  "link":"#"
 },
 {
  "image":"http://placehold.it/155x50",
  "title":"Project 3",
                "content":"content project 3",
  "link":"#"
 }
 ,
 {
  "image":"http://placehold.it/155x50",
  "title":"Project 3",
                "content":"content project 3",
  "link":"#"
 }
]

Comment: it's because in your `layout`, you are printing the whole object which result in `[object Object]`. Instead you need to access its property such as `title`, `content` or whatever you need. to access title, for example, use `li= #{obj.title}` instead of `li= obj`

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the answer as best answer to help others who has the same problem as yours.

Answer (score 1):

You should not convert your `JSON` object as a string. Basically you need to change the below line,

```
  var data = JSON.stringify(file)
```

as,

```
  var data = file
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: There is no need to parse the `file` because it's actually an object.

Comment: I was try try that and i get this:
Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: Can you try removing `JSON.parse` and pass it as `var data=file` (See my updated post)?

Comment: @agtabesh Yeah... Spot on!

Comment: @Łukasz yes, because it's actually an object. you just need to remove `var data = JSON.stringify(file)` and pass `file` as `objs` which means res.render('index', { title: 'test', objs: file });

Comment: res.render('index', { title: 'test', objs: JSON.stringify(file) }); gives me same result but i have in console:
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Comment: @Łukasz you need to put a `return` before `res.render('index', { title: 'test', objs: file });` and move your `console.log(file)` before that.

Comment: @Łukasz I'll add a new answer

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = require('data.json')
return res.render('index', { title: 'test', products: data });
```

pug file:

```
each product in products
        tr
          td= product._id
          td= product.name
          td= product.sorting
```

thanks for help

Comment: You're absolutely correct.  Express isn't going to automagically "understand" your JSON: you need to break it down into "records" (products) and "fields" (product._id, product.name, etc).  Glad you got it working, glad you shared your solution.  But I'm curious why SO it showing this as "active" ... two years after you posted it!